# Delete Second Occurence of Element in List - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to write a function that deletes the second occurrence of an element in a list.
Currently, I've written a function that removes the first element:

```
    removeFirst _ [] = [] 
    removeFirst a (x:xs) | a == x    = xs
                          | otherwise = x : removeFirst a xs
```

as a starting point. However,I'm not sure this function can be accomplished with list comprehension. Is there a way to implement this using map?

EDIT: Now I have added a removeSecond function which calls the first

```
    deleteSecond :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
    deleteSecond _ [] = []
    deleteSecond a (x:xs) | x==a = removeFirst a xs
                  | otherwise = x:removeSecond a xs
```

However now the list that is returned removes the first AND second occurrence of an element.

Comment: `map` returns a list of the same length as its input, you're looking for a list that is shorter than the input.

Comment: Your code contains two functions: `removeFirst` and `deleteFirst`. I'm assuming it's a typo?

Comment: Yes that is a typo, sorry. I will modify that.

Comment: Just wondering if your eventual intent here is to remove all but the first occurrence? Have you looked at `nub`? (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, assuming you've got `removeFirst` - how about searching for the first occurence, and then using `removeFirst` on the remaining list?

```
removeSecond :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
removeSecond _ [] = []
removeSecond a (x:xs) | x==a = x:removeFirst a xs
                      | otherwise = x:removeSecond a xs
```

Comment: Oh wow. I hadn't even considered that thank you. I'm still trying to learn Haskell and I'm finding even simple tasks to be very challenging.

Comment: If I may bother you for one more second, the remove second is still removing the first element as well. Do you know a good way to avoid this?

Comment: I've had a typo and fixed it - try the current code. Tell me if it's still not working.

Answer (score 3):

You could also implement this as a fold.

```
removeNth :: Eq a => Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
removeNth n a = concatMap snd . scanl go (0,[])
  where go (m,_) b | a /= b    = (m,   [b])
                   | n /= m    = (m+1, [b])
                   | otherwise = (m+1, [])
```

and in action:

```
λ removeNth 0 1 [1,2,3,1]
[2,3,1]
λ removeNth 1 1 [1,2,3,1]
[1,2,3]
```

I used `scanl` rather than `foldl` or `foldr` so it could both pass state left-to-right and work on infinite lists:

```
λ take 11 . removeNth 3 'a' $ cycle "abc"
"abcabcabcbc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an instinctive implementation using functions provided by `List`:

```
import List (elemIndices);
removeSecond x xs = case elemIndices x xs of
        (_:i:_) -> (take i xs) ++ (drop (i+1) xs)
        _ -> xs

removeNth n x xs = let indies = elemIndices x xs
                   in if length indies < n
                      then xs
                      else let idx = indies !! (n-1)
                           in (take idx xs) ++ (drop (idx+1) xs)
```

Note: This one cannot handle infinite list, and its performance may not be good for very large list.